# What shortcut will make Eclipse displaying the javadoc section of the method I am on? It's not Shift-F2 that leads to the top of the class javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, javadoc

If I put my mouse over a *Java* method in *Eclipse*, I can have a bit of its javadoc.

But sometimes it's not convenient to read or incomplete because *Eclipse* is tricked by many javadocs abilities that it doesn't handle correctly =>
I don't want to see the hover help *Eclipse* is able to display over a method, I want to look at its real javadoc.

What is the keyboard shortcut to go on a method description in the javadoc page when your mouse is on it or it is selected?

It's **not** `Shift-F2`

that goes on the to of the javadoc page for the whole class the method belongs to, and not on the method itself.
A `Shift-F2` done on `exists()` in `new File("abc").exists()` leads me here :

[image]

What is the *Eclipse* shortcut that will lead me to the method description directly?

Comment: Have read read this? [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840902/how-do-i-get-eclipse-to-show-the-entire-javadoc-for-a-class/39827979)

Comment: @MuhKandaWibawaPutra Yes thanks. But it doesn't explain how to go to the javadoc description of a specific method. It explain how to look at the whole javadoc class, what I'm not willing to. It writes: "_Javadoc View will open the full documentation at the right position_" with `Shift-F2`, and even for a method, but I'm asking especially this question because it's not the case.

Comment: The JavaDoc View is a view inside Eclipse. I don't think there's a function to take you to the web page with the JavaDoc--that'd take you out of the IDE.

Comment: You can look at the hover info (f2 is handy here, to "freeze" the window), or you can look at the javadoc view after clicking on the element (hover won't do it), they will both show the same information. I'm not aware of any "tricks" that you say cause problems in Eclipse.