# Eclipse not showing javadocs

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I have JDK 7 and eclipse JUNO installed on my windows 7 system .Both of them are working fine and eclipse is very well compiling my Java apps and running them as well .

But when I roll-over my cursor on syntax,then it is not showing its description.It says :

`This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc.`

for every element.
I could not find anything useful on the google and also there is no similar post on StackOverflow.

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you given it a URL from which it can load javadocs?

Comment: This has to have been answered previously on the interwebs - what have your searches shown you?

Comment: @duffymo :I have reinstalled my windows today ,but I never gave such a URL to eclipse when i previously installed it and it still was working fine.

Comment: IMO you don't need to give it an URL, just use a JDK and not a simple JRE library...

Comment: You reinstalled Windows?  Hopefully not because of this problem.  A simple Google search would give you the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870448/how-to-attach-source-or-javadoc-in-eclipse-for-any-jar-file-e-g-javafx

Comment: @duffymo You don't want to know how many people solve their abitrary computer problems by reinstalling Windows... ;)

Comment: @duffymo :I didn't reinstalled windows to solve this problem ,but it crashed and that's why i had to reinstall windows and eclipse as well,and the problem arose.

Comment: @brimborium - I go a step further.  When my machine crashes I set it on fire and get a new one.  I don't like taking chances.

Comment: What would the procedure be to get the "closed as not a real question" flag removed from this question? Because I think it is a valid question that can clear up the difference between JDK and JRE for many users (the view count suggests that the question comes up often).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Are you sure your eclipse works with a JDK and not a JRE? Go look in `Project>Properties>Java Build Path` in the tab `libraries` and see if you have linked a JDK or JRE.

For instance here, a JDK is used:

[image]

If you only have JRE's installed, you need to install a JDK first (find it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)), then in Eclipse go to `Windows>Preferences>Java>Installed JREs` and add your JDK there. Then you can add it as a library in your project settings (in the screenshot above)...

Comment: :Yes ,i said that applications are running well from eclipse. There is only `JRE System Library`.

Comment: Well they also run well if you have linked a JRE, but the Javadocs will not show up in that case IMO...

Comment: :How can I link the JDK,then ?

Comment: You need to install a JDK first (find it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)), then in Eclipse go to `Windows>Preferences>Java>Installed JREs` and add your JDK there. Then you can add it as a library in your project settings (in the screenshot above)...

Comment: :Thanx a lot , the JDk was already installed but eclipse was using the default jre.,not the JDK.

Comment: It tends to do that, yes... ;) Glad I could help.

Comment: I don't get why using a JDK solves the problem, but it solves it. Thank you.

Comment: @AbelMorelos The normal **JRE** contains the Java Runtime with focus on being as fast, efficient and as small as possible, so standard users can conveniently download and use it to run Java programs. The **JDK** (Java Developer Kit) is directed towards the developer. It still got everything the JRE got, but has additionally the Javadoc (and several other things) included. Hope that answers your question. ;)