# Using JSch with eclipse (Android project)

Tags: android, eclipse, jsch

I am using JSch with my Android project in eclipse and I am having one small problem. When I try to get the baloon popup documentation (tooltips) in the editor for JSch functions, all I ever get is (for example):

```
void com.jcraft.jsch.Session.disconnect()
Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc 
  and hence no Javadoc could be found.
```

No documentation about the command, what errors it can throw, etc.

I tried adding the javadocs into the project, but either I did it wrong, or there is something wrong with the format of the javadocs.

I've imported classes before and I have always seen the tips pop up, but not with JSch. How do I get more documentation in the editor for the JSch library?

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9870554/1321873)?

Comment: Oh yeah, I should have mentioned that. I did see instructions like that (wasn't the same page), and tried setting it up like that. I put a copy of the javadocs in a folder in the project and pointed that setting to the folder, but still nothing. I've never had to do that for any other library, so I wasn't sure if it was something specific with JSch, or if I did that wrong, or if that wasn't necessary at all and I should have done something else. I got the javadocs from here: http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suppose Eclipse tries to extract the Javadocs from the source code, and JSch's normal sources don't contain any Javadoc comments. Not sure how to solve this.