# Where can I download the JavaDoc for JPA 2.0?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

In Eclipse, I tried geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar > right click > Properties > Javadoc Location > Javadoc URL > Javadoc Location Path: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html > Validate...

but it said it could not find package-list or index.html. I also removed the HTML file from the path and it still would not work. I could not find a JAR file to download either. I have Google plugin install BTW.

Comment: Interim solution: https://glassfish.java.net/nonav/javaee5/api/. However, that is for Java 5 so it likely out of date. Using Java 7 and JPA 2.

Comment: are you using maven or this is standalone jar that you have added in your project.

Comment: @Rupesh I am not using Maven. I'm using Google Eclipse plugin, which includes JARs for AppEngine and JPA.

Comment: I just provided solution assuming you are using maven :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wandered around Oracle's site trying different paths and found it!

> http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/

This will work in Eclipse and validate. It has full text descriptions for things like EntityManager. It has ALL Java EE APIs as well, so you can use it for other JARs that are missing docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have included the jar using maven dependency then you can download javadoc and source code by enabling following settings.

In Eclipse click on Window >> Preferences >> type maven in search box >> and enable as shown

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't find it on Geronimo website, then Maven Central Repository is a good place: [from this search result](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.geronimo.specs%22%20AND%20a%3A%22geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec%22) (version 3.0, if you need another one, just change the query), download `javadoc.jar`, decompress it somewhere and you are set. Of course, if you are not already using Maven to manage your projects.

Comment: Ok that was nice, however the descriptions of all methods are empty! For example, EntityManager. I also tried 2.0. I was expecting at least "see also...".

Comment: A quick inspection of the source code shows that those classes/interfaces are not documented at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source in the [Apache SVN repo](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/geronimo/specs/tags/geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0/)

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no JavaDoc comments in those classes. They are bare Interfaces.

Comment: If you want Javadocs, hibernate-jpa-2.0-api is a better option. JPA 2.0 is the specification, several vendors have implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

When You download ObjectDB.jar package, the java docs are present inside it.
The the file will be present inside doc folder and it will be named as api-javadoc.zip.
 For adding it in netbeans do the following:
1. click tool
2. click java platform
3. goto javadocs
4. click on add folder/jar files
5. browse to add the api-javadoc.jar file 
6. click close
7. restart netbeans

enjoy..:)