# Java Decompiler plugin in Eclipse with JavaDoc

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I add a decompiler plugin `JadClipse` in Eclipse but I am facing a issue that decompiler removes the JavaDoc from the code. Only the simple code is made available, can anybody suggest me any available Eclipse plugin to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

JAD doesn't remove the JavaDoc - there simply is no JavaDoc in compiled code.

What you want is to add JavaDoc to decompiled code. There is no plugin for that (and I think writing one wouldn't be easy).

If you have the JavaDoc as a JAR, you can [tell Eclipse to show it in the project's setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870448/how-to-attach-source-or-javadoc-in-eclipse-for-any-jar-file-e-g-javafx)s. That way, you might be able to see the docs when you hover over a place where a method is **used** - if you hover over the decompiled method, this probably won't work (I think the decompiled source will take precedence over anything else).

Answer (score 0):

The solution to add manually each javadoc is a bit heavy if you have many librairies in your project, which is often the case.

If you have Maven integration, the solution to have the javadoc accessible is to tell Maven to download it.

In Eclipse Project Explorer :

Right-click on your projet -> Maven -> Download JavaDoc

There should be an equivalent for Graddle which I've never used yet.