# How do I import the javafx correctly into eclipse? ("The import cannot be resolved")

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I looked on many similar questions but the solutions didnt help me :(

[This is my openjfx lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OItkn.png)

[This is the jfx doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQw8W.png)

I can import the lib in 2 ways:

[1. In the java build path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxlCr.png)
I can use this way all the classes without problems... BUT i cant load the java doc or source, if i do, it does not work.

or...

[2. edit the installed JRE definitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8JnU.png)
This way I add like explained in other Questions the jfxrt.jar in the installed jre and i give it the source and doc. AND  it WORKS! ... nearly... The documentation works now... but not all imports. :(

```
import javafx.application.Platform;       //this works
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;     //this works
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;  //this works
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;    //this works
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;    //this DOES NOT work :(
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;//this DOES NOT work :(
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;        //this DOES NOT work :(
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;    //this works again ._.
```

The error i get is:
"The import javafx.scene.layout.Background cannot be resolved"

Well... when doing the 1st step (from [This is my openjfx lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OItkn.png)). I have absolutly no import issues and i can work perfectly, but the doc doesnt work.

And now with [2. edit the installed JRE definitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8JnU.png) the doc does work but i have import issues with certain stuff and i dont understand why :(

Obviously I am doing something wrong... (i am pretty new to java)

my java -version:

```
java version "13" 2019-09-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13+33)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13+33, mixed mode, sharing)
```

(i had some bug earlier using the fx and it got fixed by updating my eclipse 2019-09)

Well. i hope you can help me ^^

Comment: I also tryed e(fx)clipse and added the fx-sdk in the buildpath but could not resolve every import

Comment: Where did you get a `jfxrt.jar` for JavaFX 11+?? That doesn't exist anymore. If it is from an older version (10 or less), that might explain some import issues. But this is not the way to do it. See https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run JavaFX 11+ on Eclipse, you have to follow the documentation here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse.

If you are not using Maven/Gradle build tools:

- Download the JavaFX 13 SDK from [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/)
- Create a JavaFX13 library with the JavaFX jars.
- Add the VM arguments to your run configuration.

**JavaDoc and Sources**

To get javadoc and sources working, you shouldn't add a (very old) `jfxrt.jar`, that is from and old JavaFX version, so you will get mismatches because some changes in packages.

The proper way to do it, if you already have your JavaFX13 library is:

- Edit the library (`Eclipse -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries -> JavaFX13`), and display all the jars included. If you display the content of any of these jars, you will probably see:

  ```
  Source attachment: (None)
  Javadoc location: (None)
  ```

  - Jar by jar, select `Source attachment`, press the `Edit...` button, select `External location`, and find the `src.zip` file under the lib folder of your local JavaFX SDK.

[image: Source and Javadoc]

- Jar by jar, select `Javadoc location`, press the `Edit...` button, select Javadoc URL, and paste `https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/`.
- Apply and close, when done.

You should now get Javadoc when hovering any JavaFX class, and also access to source code when Ctrl+Click a JavaFX class.

Comment: Yes that is the solution... I swear i did the same thing before and it didnt worked xD Thats why i tried the 2nd step with the old jar :D
But now i restarted the computer and tried again the 1st step and the doc worked, too xD

Comment: I've seen a lot of junk for this topic; this is the only post that is straightforward and addresses the issue I had.

Comment: If you have downloaded the docs from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/, you have to give path in all jars' Javadoc location option to the root folder where 'element-list' file is located.