# Get JavaFX on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am working on a project for uni using JavaFX using a mac. The instructions say to download Java 11 Zulu JDK.

When I imported the starter code, there were errors as expected. But I followed the instructions for the project:

- Go to Eclipse -> Preferences. On the left, under Java select Installed JREs then click Add. Ensure Standard VM is selected and click Next.
- Click Directory and select the directory of the Zulu JDK you unzipped in step 1. Change JRE name to exactly jdk-jfx.
- Click Finish then Apply and Close

This doesn't import the javafx library. I can't even find a reference to javaFX in the Zulu JDK files. Can anyone help.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/58354661/203657

Comment: Try it via Help->Eclipse Marketplace, search for "e(fx)clipse" and the install it. It automaticly adds everything you need.