# Add JavaFX Javadoc to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I installed JavaFX 11 in Eclipse using a custom User Library with JavaFX in it, but now I would like to be able to see the documentation in the tooltip windows in Eclipse. Currently it is showing me this:

### [image: Correctly implemented Javadoc]

### [image: Incorrectly implemented Javadoc]

How do I implement this correctly?

Comment: I think you should attach javadoc source to the library.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58355210/3956070).

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs quite often. But there is a simple solution; add the preferences (Add the JRE in your JDK similar like that).

For more information please see here: [Solution JRE](https://blog.stefan-macke.com/2011/09/16/display-javadoc-tooltips-in-eclipse/)

After adding the javadoc source to library it should work (hopefully).