# How to add the javadocs from XChart in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I've followed the instructions from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870448/how-to-attach-source-or-javadoc-in-eclipse-for-any-jar-file-e-g-javafx) on how to add javadocs in eclispe. But i'm still not doing something right or maybe [XChart](https://knowm.org/open-source/xchart/) doesn't have downloadable javadocs? Which i don't think is the issue?

What am i doing wrong? I tried editing the javadoc location for both a file path and the url path, but nothing seems to be working. What do i need to do, restart eclipse?

For the url i entered this [link](https://knowm.org/javadocs/xchart/index.html) but that did not work.

For the file path i tried referencing the actual folder that contained everything from the download. it was named xchart-3.6.1

I also tried referencing the jar file for the file path but that didn't work either.

My goal is hover my mouse over a method and read the description and any information about it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enhanced-class-decompiler` plugin for eclipse which you can find from following link:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enhanced-class-decompiler

Comment: What does this do? How do i use it? how does it help read javadocs that eclipse by it self cant do, if that is the case?