# Custom Javadoc not showing in IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, doc

I have built a library and linked it to my Eclipse project as an `External JAR`.
Though the library works well, I couldn't make the Javadoc I wrote appear, as Eclipse keeps showing me:

[image]

I've read through some similar posts and they all refer to the javadoc file location, but I have no separate file for Javadoc. Everything is written above fields and methods with basic annotations.
How am I supposed to "link" a javadoc that is already present in the library files ? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think your question's a duplicate, but it is very similar to this other one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870448/how-to-attach-source-or-javadoc-in-eclipse-for-any-jar-file-e-g-javafx

Answer (score 1):

You could export the jar, and in the export window you can mark the option **export java source files and resources**

I know this insn't the ideal fix(cause you would be exporting your source code) but it does work

Comment: Thanks! Actually I don't care as the code is open source. However, I'm curious to know if there is a way of making this javadoc readable without doing so. I guess no as the files get obfuscated.

Comment: Maybe you're supposed to run the Javadoc tool and place the resulting HTML files in the JAR file. How do they do it with JUnit? Although JUnit's open source, I doubt any of the three major IDEs include the JUnit source, but I haven't checked.