# Why is Eclipse's Javadoc malfunctioning when using an http Javadoc location?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, guice

When I go to the project properties libraries tab and specify a path to an online javadoc using the "Javadoc location path" field populated with `http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc`, I get a "naked" javadoc in the hover or javadoc view that shows some of the correct information like "since API 3.0".  But it's missing all of the text documentation and the list of public methods.

Strangely if I click "open attached Javadoc in a browser", then all of the correct information is displayed.  Is this an Eclipse bug?  A Guice Javadoc formatting bug?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the first answer to the question ["How do I add the Java API Documentation to Eclipse?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600172/how-do-i-add-the-java-api-documentation-to-eclipse) will answer your question as well.  The relevant quote, in case the link stops working, is:

> Eclipse doesn't pull the tooltips from the javadoc location. It only uses the javadoc location to prepend to the link if you [select] 'open in browser'. You need to download and attach the source [...] in order to get the tooltips.

I did not find a source for the above claim, although it seemed to work on my installation as well.

Comment: I've also had it working by downloading just the javadocs and referencing them in locally (useful for javadocs to 3rd party libraries where you don't have access to the source code).