# I can not react to Math.reverseBytes in Java

Tags: java

I try to use Math.reverseBytes in Java but giving error : ***The method reverseBytes() is undefined for the type Math***

As you know it is static type . Why cant i use it?

```
import java.lang.Integer;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = Math.reverseBytes();//Eclipse cannot reach this function
    }
}
```

From Java Doc - Some Information

**reverseBytes**

```
public static int reverseBytes(int i);
```

Returns the value obtained by reversing the order of the bytes in the two's complement representation of the specified int value.

Returns:
the value obtained by reversing the bytes in the specified int value.

Since:
1.5

Comment: The Javadoc you cite for the Math class does not exist. Not a real question.

Comment: You are looking for `Integer.reverseBytes(int i)`, therefore use `int x = Integer.reverseByte( yourIntValue )`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There *IS* no "Math.reverseBytes()".

Integer.reverseBytes() or Short.reverseBytes(), yes.  Math - no.

PS:

You should definitely install JavaDoc in your Eclipse.  Here's how:

- [How do I add the Java API documentation to Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600172/how-do-i-add-the-java-api-documentation-to-eclipse)

Comment: i have never heard about that method, i will look up now.

Answer (score 1):

This method does not exist in Math package. 
in your code you have imported java.lang.Integer, so did you mean

> Integer.reverseBytes()

?