# Create new Java project, java preferences unavailable

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, eclipse-indigo

[image: preferences screen]I finished installing Eclipse 3.7.2 (Indigo) on my Ubuntu 12.04 system.

I am unable to have any options pertaining to either creating a Java project, running one as a Java project, can't find any of the Java preferences for JRE settings... There is no Java Development Toolkit in the Help section. I had all this earlier, I am not sure what changed. I am assuming that this has something to do with the SDK but have no other clue.

[image: installed components]

Comment: If you can't get a good answer here, this would also be on topic at askubuntu.com. You could probably get a better answer regarding your system setup.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion John, i posted this here since I think the problem is pertaining to either JDK or Eclipse, rather than it being a matter of the OS - just stated the OS to be on the safe side. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install your preffered JDK, then go `Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs` and point to the fresh install.

Also, check `Preferences -> General -> Capabilities`. Make sure you have `Development` selected.

Comment: That is the problem, I do not even have "Java" under preferences. Nor is Capabilities available. Anyway I can get a screen shot uploaded here? I could show what's available and what not...

Comment: @John please see ^ comment. I do not have any of these options available. Does that help understand the problem better?

Comment: @mhere4alittlewhile I doubt that you don't have `General -> Capabilities` available. Please update your question with a screenshot of Eclipse's Preferences Dialog.

Comment: Hey @GGrec I guess I need to have better reputation points to upload an image. I will get back to you with the screenshot once I am beyond 10 :(

Comment: @mhere4alittlewhile Voted up your question. You now have 11 rep, congrats! :-)

Comment: Hey @GGrec, added the image.

Comment: @mhere4alittlewhile The explanation is that the `Capabilities` preference page is found in the Eclipse SDK plugin... you might want to check out Eclipse's Updates via `Install New Software` ([paste this link there](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7)). I think you may have downloaded Classic Eclipse. You need to install Eclipse Platform and SDK for 3.7

Comment: Eclipse Platform is already installed. There are conflicting dependencies when I install Eclipse SDK. I will attach a text file with the details of the components already installed.

Comment: @mhere4alittlewhile This is taking you too long to solve. I suggest you consider donwloading another build of eclipse (e.g. for RCP and RAP developers), or even another version (e.g. Juno, Kepler). Take the more convenient solution. :-)

Comment: Ahh,okay guess I'll just download it again. thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You might not have a system JRE installed. Press `ctl + alt + T` to open your Terminal
 and then try running:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

Note: this will install Java 1.7, if you want 1.6 then you have to specify that

Then in Eclipse, make sure you have your environment setup correctly.

If you want the official JavaDoc, here how to set it up:

[How do I add the Java API documentation to Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600172/how-do-i-add-the-java-api-documentation-to-eclipse)

Here is a link to the JavaDoc that you can use in your preferences:

- http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Comment: I already have installed JDK 7. I'm still facing the problem. Also, I understand that for Java development I would not be requiring JRE if I have JDK - is that correct?

Comment: Also, I have the PDF for the Java documentation on this link that you provided,so I do not absolutely need it in the help section :) thanks for the link! The main problem is the ability to get started writing and executing Java code! :(