# how should i add JavaFX API documentation to eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, api, javafx

I have installed JDK 8 (1.8) and i am using eclipse .The problem is that the tooltip does not work for JavaFX methods and classes(it works well for other methods and classes) .When i hover over a built-in method or class i get this message : [image]

And also when i go to the documentation files by holding ctrl key and clicking on a method or class identifier it shows this :[image]

so how should i fix this?

also there was a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600172/how-do-i-add-the-java-api-documentation-to-eclipse) but the answers were not helpful to me so i asked this question.

Answer (score 4):

You should use e(fx)clipse who fixes this for you automatically else you'll have to fix your "Installed JREs" (in your preference) and point the source location of jfxrt.jar to the sources inside your JDK

Comment: i have tried to install that extension to my eclipse but i couldn't so can you explain a little more about the alternative way of fixing this problem .

Comment: you could have downloaded a full version from http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/install.html (you need the nightly download until we release 0.9.0 on 31th January) - it will give you fxml and css editors who you'll really need to really work on JavaFX applications.

Anyways: 
 * Open your Preferences
 * Java > Installed JREs
 * Select Java SE 8 .... and hit Edit button
 * Locate jfxrt.jar
 * Hit the "Source Attachment..." button
 * Locate the javafx-src.zip in your JDK