# Missing Javadoc in Eclipse for JRE 9

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9

**Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2)** fails to load standard javadoc when I select my **JRE 9** install as default JRE.

Is that a bug?

When I switch back to **JRE 8** it works.

**EDIT**

So, I was a bit short on that one, let me explain. When I select a JRE for Eclipse (Preferences > Java > Installed JREs), should it be a JRE9, a JDK9, a JRE8 or a JDK8 location, when I `Edit` it, I can see in the jrt-fs.jar (9) or in each separated jar including rt.jar (8) a `Source attachment` location (empty for JRE which is normal) and `Javadoc location` (official HTTP URL).

That's why I expect the Javadoc to display even with a JRE.

Now when I hover over a standard Java class, say `java.io.IOException` or `java.lang.String` for example:

- with JRE9 the Javadoc is not found in the tooltip
- with JDK9 it is found, but:

  - if I click "open attached Javadoc in browser" I get an Oracle NotFound error page looking for `http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html` which is the URL in the Javadoc Location of JRE9 & JDK9
  - if I click a link in the tooltip, e.g. `java.io.InputStream`, I get an Eclipse error: `Exception:org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaModelException: I/O exception` which is `Caused by: java.io.IOException: null`, followed by a `Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\lib\jrt-fs.jar\java.base is not on its project's build path]`
- with JRE8 or JDK8 the Javadoc is found in the tooltip as well as in the `attached Javadoc in browser` (`docs.oracle.com/javase/8/...`)

So there are at least three problems:

- How come my tooltip doesn't work with JRE9? The [possible duplicate question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600172/how-do-i-add-the-java-api-documentation-to-eclipse) says that `Eclipse doesn't pull the tooltips from the javadoc location`, so where does it pull it from?

  - *[ANSWERED]* from the source code if any. So I attached `[jdk9_path]/lib/src.zip` as `Source Location` in my JRE9 and it works.
- How come Eclipe is looking for `jrt-fs.jar\java.base`, which does not exist?

  - *[ANSWERED]* I found the answer for that one: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=522054 still unsolved to this day.
- How come JDK9 & JRE9 come with an incorrect Javadoc Location (`http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add the Java API documentation to Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600172/how-do-i-add-the-java-api-documentation-to-eclipse)

Comment: The JRE does not include the javadoc tool or API, are you sure this worked with JRE 8? Maybe it is actually using JDK 8.

Answer (score 0):

**JREs** are the bare runtimes, they do not contain the compiler, packaging tools, sources, or **documentation**. The easiest solution is often to use a **JDK** instead.